# LuaLaTeX and PDFX result in hyperref warning

Tags: hyperref, luatex, warnings, pdfx

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{pdfx}

\begin{document}
test
\end{document}
```

If compiled via `lualatex test.tex` I receive the following warning:

```
Package hyperref Warning: Wrong driver `hpdftex.def';
(hyperref)                pdfTeX is running in PDF mode.
(hyperref)                Forcing driver `hluatex.def'.


Package hyperref Message: Driver: hluatex.
```

I'm not sure how severe the warning ist. Can someone clarify if I can ignore this warning, or even better how I can resolve the warning.

LuaTeX, Version 0.95.0 (TeX Live 2016)

pdfx 1.5.8/2016/05/03

Comment: You can ignore the warning: hyperref loads the correct driver. Really resolve it can only the author of the package.

Comment: Agreed. Not a problem.

Comment: The issue was fixed with `pdfx` 2017/05/18 v1.5.84.

Comment: If you were able to update to TL17 this question would be solved. Is that an option for you?

Comment: Yes, TL17 with the latest updates solved the problem for me. Thanks for the heads up and fixing the problem!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because issue with luatex changes fixed by package in later releases.