# Command \textsuperscript unavailable in encoding TU

Tags: hyperref, luatex, pdfx

Consider the following MWE using `pdfx` v1.5.8:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a-2b]{pdfx}
\begin{document}
Text\textsuperscript{Text}
\end{document}
```

Since updating my MiKTeX packages today, I get

```
Command \textsuperscript unavailable in encoding TU.
```

when using LuaTeX, Version 1.0.4 (MiKTeX 2.9.6300 64-bit) and

```
Command \textsuperscript unavailable in encoding OT1.
```

when using pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (MiKTeX 2.9.6300 64-bit). Additionally, the warning

```
Wrong driver `hpdftex.def';(hyperref) pdfTeX is running in PDF mode.
```

appears as described in [LuaLaTeX and PDFX result in hyperref warning](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/360153). Before updating the packages, this example worked perfectly. Do you have any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This has been discussed last year in the chat http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/31191393#31191393.

pdfx make \textsuperscript encoding dependant but doesn't setup a suitable default. Something like this should work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\let\tmpa\textsuperscript
\DeclareTextCommandDefault{\textsuperscript}{\tmpa}

\usepackage{pdfx}

\begin{document}

Text\textsuperscript{Text} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: The issue was fixed recently with `pdfx` 2017/05/18 v1.5.84. You can skip the workaround when updating the package.